# Is it possible to pass ActionEvent to "onMouseClick" on a label?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Basically, I want to be able to access the ActionEvent when a label is clicked

**Why am I not using a button?**
It's for styling reasons, I don't like the default actions the button gives on hovering

**Why do I need ActionEvent?**
I need to be able to capture the event to process loading a new scene:

```
public void startNewGame(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent tableViewParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GameSetup.fxml"));
    Scene tableViewScene = new Scene(tableViewParent);

    Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    window.setScene(tableViewScene);
    window.show();
```

So, is it possible to find the ActionEvent with mouse click function? Or maybe there is a simpler way to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using the `MouseEvent` passed to the `onMouseClicked` handler? Also, you can style the `Button` differently so it doesn't do what you don't like it doing (e.g. stop it from changing anything on mouse hover).

Comment: @Slaw I literally just changed ActionEvent to MouseEvent and it worked. As you can probably tell I am very new to Javafx, still making stupid mistakes. But really, I appreciate your help because god knows I would have spent at least 2 hours trying to figure that out if you didn't say anything!

Comment: _It's for styling reasons, I don't like the default actions the button gives on hovering_ so one of your next steps in learning is css in fx :)

Comment: Note that a `MOUSE_CLICKED` event triggers on a click of ***any*** mouse button. If you want to restrict yourself to the primary one, you need to test the button clicked. Otherwise left, right and middle mouse buttons trigger the scene change.

Comment: @fabian got it, thanks!